# How to selectively apply a script to an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a script that makes textareas expand to fit the the text inside of them. I want this to be applied all the textarea's on my website, except for one. Is there anyway to stop the script for one element.

Script being used:

```
var autoExpand = function (field) {

// Reset field height
field.style.height = 'inherit';

// Get the computed styles for the element
var computed = window.getComputedStyle(field);

  // Calculate the height
  var height = parseInt(computed.getPropertyValue('border-top-width'), 10)
             + parseInt(computed.getPropertyValue('padding-top'), 10)
             + field.scrollHeight
             + parseInt(computed.getPropertyValue('padding-bottom'), 10)
             + parseInt(computed.getPropertyValue('border-bottom-width'), 
  10);

  field.style.height = height + 'px';

  };

  document.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
  if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'textarea') return;
  autoExpand(event.target);
  }, false);
```

Textarea:

```
<textarea id="sendie" maxlength = '100' ></textarea>
```

Comment: yes, don't apply it to the one you don't want to apply it to - probably change line 37

Comment: What is the script and how does it target the text areas?

Comment: save your selector list to an array. Filter the array to remove the undesired div. Apply function to the rest of the selector list.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas It just applies the affects to all textareas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

By ID:

```
#sendie {
  resize: none;
}
```

That don't work, work it into your function

```
  document.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
      if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'textarea') return;
      autoExpand(event.target);
      document.getElementById("sendie").style.resize = "none"
  }, false);
```

Assuming "sendie" is the one you don't want to mess with.

Comment: I editted my response. I really think that the reworked JS is gonna work for you.